# What is the use and functionality of render in react-native?

Tags: react-native

what is the actual use of render().why we use this? Can we use this in both functional and class based components?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  } 
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A functional component essentially *is* the `render` function of its class companion.

```
const render = props => <div />
```

same as:

```
class extends Component {
  render() { return <div /> } // props via this.props
}
```

It's the most important function in React as it tells your target (web, or native in your case) what to display on the screen.